# Mount entry in /etc/fstab with SSHFS and a proxy

Tags: networking, xfce, fstab, sshfs

I'm trying to mount a remote disk using SSHFS that is not directly accessible, i.e. I need to use a proxy, like `local -> proxy -> remote`. I'm using only key-based auth for both.
The following command works:

```bash
sshfs -o IdentityFile='[PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_REMOTE]' -o ProxyCommand='ssh -q -i [PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_PROXY] -W %h:%p [PROXY_USER]@[PROXY]' [REMOTE_USER]@[REMOTE]:[SOURCE] [DESTINATION]
```

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work as an entry in `/etc/fstab`; the current one is:

```bash
[REMOTE_USER]@[REMOTE]:[SOURCE] [DESTINATION] fuse.sshfs delay_connect,rw,noauto,_netdev,reconnect,ProxyCommand='ssh -q -i [PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_REMOTE] -W %h:%p [PROXY_USER]@[PROXY]',ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3,IdentityFile=[PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_REMOTE]' 0 0
```

but when running `mount [DESTINATION]`, I get an error:

```
mount: /etc/fstab: parse error at line X -- ignored
```

I've tried replacing `ProxyCommand` with `ProxyJump`, like so:

```bash
[REMOTE_USER]@[REMOTE]:[SOURCE] [DESTINATION] fuse.sshfs delay_connect,rw,noauto,_netdev,reconnect,ProxyJump=[PROXY_USER]@[PROXY],ServerAliveInterval=15,ServerAliveCountMax=3,IdentityFile=[PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_REMOTE]' 0 0
```

This works for the command-line version, and `mount [DESTINATION]` doesn't report errors, but I keep getting `Input/output error` when trying to access it.

On the other hand, the below works when using `mount [DESTINATION]` (and if the key file for the proxy has been added to the SSH agent), but I'm still getting a prompt for the password (for the proxy) if mounting the remote graphically (XFCE 4):

```
[REMOTE_USER]@[REMOTE]:[SOURCE] [DESTINATION] fuse.sshfs rw,noauto,_netdev,ProxyJump=[PROXY_USER]@[PROXY],IdentityFile=[PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_PROXY],IdentityFile=[PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_REMOTE] 0 0
```

Any ideas to make it work via the graphical prompt?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1410187) from superuser.SE has the right idea; I had to make some modifications though, the right configuration seems to be (requires OpenSSH 7.3 or above):

#### `~/.ssh/config`

```
Host remote
    ProxyJump proxy
    HostName [REMOTE]
    User [REMOTE_USER]
    IdentityFile [PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_REMOTE]

Host proxy
    HostName [PROXY]
    User [PROXY_USER]
    IdentityFile [PATH_TO_KEY_FOR_PROXY]
```

#### `/etc/fstab`

```
remote:[SOURCE] [DESTINATION] fuse.sshfs rw,noauto,_netdev 0 0
```

Owing to the previous unsuccessful connection attempts, `gvfsd` was hanging the file manager, so I also had to do `killall gvfsd`, which did the trick, and I can now automatically mount the remote without issues (both using `mount [DESTINATION]` and in the GUI).